# Indexes in string - plotting graph

Tags: python-3.x

How to write indexes in axes when I plot a graph? 
I tried this, however, indexes are not print properly.
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.xlabel(r'$K$_1 (km s^{-1}'))

[image: picture]

Comment: I don't undestand, I added the picture what I mean. I didn't find it in this linked question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.xticks` to set index as values.

For more details you can check this documentation: 
https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks

Comment: So I should use `plt.xticks` instead of `plt.xlabel`?